# How to move the files names in global variable in sas

Tags: sas

Here I have declare 10 variables as: file0 to file9 and also write a code that reads files names from a particular location i.e:"D:\CSV_Files\CSV\". I want to know how to assign the files names to the corresponding declared variables.

Note: "fname" all the Files Names.

Thanks In Advance.

```
%LET file0=;
%LET file1=;
%LET file2=;
%LET file3=;
%LET file4=;
%LET file5=;
%LET file6=;
%LET file7=;
%LET file8=;
%LET file9=;



data _null_;
rc = filename("mydir","D:\CSV_Files\CSV\");
did =dopen("mydir");

if did>0 then do;
num= dnum(did);

do i=0 to num;
fname= dread(did,i);
put fname= ;
end;
end;
run;




 OutPut:

  fname=ABC.csv
  fname=XYZ.csv
  fname=ABCd.csv
  fname=WXTZ.csv
  fname=ABCDE.csv
  fname=ABCDF.csv
  fname=ABCG.csv
  fname=ABCH.csv
  fname=ABCl.csv
  fname=ABCk.csv

 Output that I require:

      file0=ABC.csv
      file1=XYZ.csv
      file2=ABCd.csv
      file3=WXTZ.csv
      file4=ABCDE.csv
      file5=ABCDF.csv
      file6=ABCG.csv
      file7=ABCH.csv
      file8=ABCl.csv
      file9=ABCM.csv
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Are you trying to create a single SAS data set or read it into multiple files? If all into one, use a wildcard in your infile statement instead of this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
call symputx(cats('FILE',i),fname);
```

There is a third parameter 'G' or 'L' for Global or Local scope, you can choose how that fits for you.  And you don't really need to Declare the FILEn variables with %LET first.

However you can probably do the work (generate some code perhaps) you plan after you have the macro variables in the same data step where you create the macro variables.

Comment: Dear, I am New in sas can u please explain how do i create global variable for the same.

Comment: Add third parameter to SYMPUTX 'G';  You may want to visit support.sas.com where you can view the online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is below although as the other answer suggests, you should probably read up on ways to declare macro variables.

The call symputx stores your variables within the first parameter.  In this case its cats('FILE',i) - Resolves to FILE1, FILE2, FILE3 etc.  I've also used to define the variable NUM.  This is because the array needs a size and you need to have a fixed value in this position.

Use this first step to open the directory and get the number of files and store it in the macro variable NUM.

```
data _null_;
  rc =    filename("mydir","D:\CSV_Files\CSV\");
    did =dopen("mydir");
    call symputx ('num', dnum(did), 'g');
    rc=close(did);
  run;
```

Declare an array of size NUM and use the next step to loop through each file and put out to the log in the format required.

```
  data _null_; 
    rc = filename("mydir","D:\CSV_Files\CSV\");
    did =dopen("mydir");

    array FILE(&num.) $128;
    do i=1 to &num.;
        FILE(i)= dread(did,i);
        call symputx(cats('FILE',i),FILE(i),'g');
        put file(i)= ;
    end;
    rc=close(did);
  run;
```

Comment: You can ask the DNUM question in the same step (your second data \_null\_ and use the value directly as the TO value in the DO I= loop.  Do you really need the array? No, just assign value from DREAD as arg 2 of SYMPUTX.

Comment: I used a separate step to generate the NUM variable as I needed it for my array and it can only be done in a separate step.  I only used an array to generate the required output assuming that Pankaj wanted the output he showed in his question.  It was more for completeness and answering all points (even if it is redundant just to show the info in the log)

Comment: But yes, you are completely correct.  It can all be done in one step if you don't want to generate the variables themselves.

Comment: What do you mean "if you don't want to generate the variables themselves"?

Comment: My output would generate variables FILE1-FILEn. In Pankaj's example he wants to see these variables shown in the log so I've shown how to do this using am array. I could have just used one step and concatenated the vars to show it but this seems neater.